# Why can't we use auto in template static member initialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static

The following code

```
template <typename MemberType>
struct Holder {
    static MemberType member;
};

template <typename MemberType>
auto Holder<MemberType>::member;
```

produces error C2371 in MSVS 2013 if we try to access Holder::member:

> error C2371: 'member' : redefinition; different basic types

However, if in initialization we use template parameter name instead of 'auto' keyword

```
template <typename MemberType>
MemberType Holder<MemberType>::member;
```

it compiles as expected. So, what is the reason why compiler is unable to infer static member type in this case?

Comment: How should it infer the type?

Comment: `auto` *deduces* a type from an initializer. There is no initializer here, the compiler can't help you

Comment: @quantdev but if I add `= MemberType()`, it still produces the same error.  So is this a case when type cannot be deduced from initializer?

Comment: The error you get doesn't make much sense anyway as `auto` isn't a type. Clang and GCC give the same types of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of a variable with a placeholder `auto`/`decltype(auto)` must have an initializer for the type of the variable to be deduced:

> The type of a variable declared using `auto` or `decltype(auto)` is deduced from its initializer. This use is allowed when declaring variables in a block (6.3), in namespace scope (3.3.6), and in a *for-init-statement* (6.5.3).
>   `auto` or `decltype(auto)` shall appear as one of the *decl-specifiers* in the *decl-specifier-seq* and the *decl-specifier-seq* shall be followed by one or more *init-declarators*, each of which shall have a non-empty *initializer*.

Your example doesn't have an initializer for the definition, so your code is ill-formed.

The definition of a static member may have a placeholder, but the problem in your example has to do with the fact that you're using templates and the declaration of the static member is dependent on the template argument. For example, this definition won't compile:

```c++
template <typename MemberType>
auto Holder<MemberType>::member = 42; // error: redefinition of 'member' with
                                    // a different type: 'int' vs 'MemberType'
```

`Holder<MemberType>` causes an implicit instantiation where the compiler will look at the declaration of `Holder<MemberType>::member`. The compiler doesn't know at the time of this instantiation whether the type deduced from the initializer (`int`) matches `MemberType`, which is why you get the strange error "`int` vs `MemberType`".

The above code works if you create an explicit specialization of the data member because `MemberType` is known at the time of the instantiation:

```c++
template <>
auto Holder<int>::member = 42; // OK, decltype(42) matches int (MemberType)
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed the point that one must initialize it inside the class in order to use `auto`.

Comment: Your first quote says it is allowed in namespace scope, as long as it's got a non-empty initializer.

Comment: @BenVoigt The `auto` placeholder can't be used in the definition because in OP's example it doesn't contain an initializer (which the first quote says it must have). However, giving the definition an initializer with `auto` works in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74f8ada287daa9b1) but not in [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cde02bf9eb9d5a5). That must be a bug in gcc.

Comment: @interphx Note that you can still use `auto` *outside* the class with an initializer. See my updated answer. But in your case the template argument `MemberType` is not known at the time of the static member definition so [`auto` can't be used](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18e3328f68856926).